# What's the difference between \hfil and \hskip0cm plus 1fil?

Tags: tex-core, tex-history, primitives, glue

What's the difference between `\hfil` and `\hskip0cm plus 1fil`? In both cases, a glue token is created that skips by zero, but with 1fil of stretchability. If you use `\hbox spread 4cm{\hfil test \hskip0cm plus 1fil}`, you'll get an hbox with "test" in the middle and 2cm on either side of empty space (showing that the two glues are sharing the space equally). In all the cases I've tested, the two have been exactly the same (including variants of `\hfil` like `\hfill` and `\vfil`).

What's the difference between the two, and if there is none, why is `\hfil` a primitive instead of a macro for `\hskip0cm plus 1fil`? Is `\hfil` always interchangeable with `\hskip0cm plus 1fil`?

Comment: Yes, the only difference is that `\hfil` is a primitive, and it's a primitive for efficiency reasons that were relevant in the late 70s/early 80s when TeX was designed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`\hfil` and `\hskip0cm plus 1fil` make identical glue items so tests such as your box example will be identical in the same way that `\hskip0cm plus 1fil` is the same as `\hskip 0 pt   plus 1fil`,  However they differ as tokens and the way they are scanned.

Notably of course, after

```
\def\zzA{\hfil}
```

and

```
\def\zzB{\hskip0cm plus 1fil}
```

Then

```
\zzA look and \zzB look
```

show different behaviour, and similarly after

```
\def\gobble#1{}


\expandafter\gobble\zzA  and \expandafter\gobble\ZZB
```

Comment: And worse: `\zzA minus \zzB minus 3mm` or `Test 2: \zzA look \zzB look`

Answer (score 21):

`\hfil` inserts a glue that is exactly equivalent (identical) to that inserted by `\hskip 0pt plus 1fil`. The only difference is that:

- `\hfil` is a primitive, so it doesn't have to scan the input text for a glue specification,
- in other words, `\hskip 0pt plus 1fil` *does* involve scanning the input for a glue spec, which can result in funny differences depending on what comes after the `1fil`.

See the clever examples in David Carlisle's answer, or even just `\hfil minus forty` versus `\hskip 0pt plus 1fil minus forty`.

---

Why does `\hfil` exist as a primitive? As TeX is one of the most-documented programs in existence, we can actually look this up. If you invoke `texdoc errorlog` (or [read it online](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/errata/errorlog.pdf)), you'll see this entry for 23 July 1979:

[image: from errorlog]

The “E” means it's a change made for “Efficiency”.

In the old (pre-TeXbook, and for TeX78) TeX manual, the one published in 1979 as part of “TeX and METAFONT: New Directions in Typesetting”, in Appendix X: Recent Extensions to TeX (page 201 of the “TeX” part of the book), it says:

> The new control sequences `\hfil`, `\hfilneg`, `\hss` are short for `\hskip 0pt plus 100000pt`, `\hskip 0pt plus -100000pt`, `\hskip plus 100000pt minus 100000pt`, respectively, and they take less TeX memory space. The vertical analogs are `\vfil`, `\vfilneg`, and `\vss`.

(At that time the `fil`/`fill`/`filll` units and orders of “infinity” didn't exist; those came later: see the entry for 7 Aug 1981 in `errorlog`.)

---

And to confirm that `\hfil` really does the same thing, we can look at the TeX program source code (around the section 1058 mentioned above) (`texdoc tex` or [read online](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tex.pdf#page=394)):

[image: 1058]
[image: 1060]

(Unfortunately the above is hard to understand unless you are familiar with the special conventions of the TeX program, but the main point is that `\hskip` and `\hfil` invoke the same internal function (procedure) `append_glue`, except that in the `\hfil` case the glue specification is a hard-coded `fil_glue`, and in the `\hskip` case it is scanned using `scan_glue`.)